# Session variable was empty in php

Tags: php, mysql, session-cookies, session-variables, session-state

login.php

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include '../config.php';
    if( (isset($_SESSION['can-id']) )) {
    header('location: ../home/profile.php');
    }
    if(isset($_POST['can-login']))
    {
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `user_credentials` WHERE `email`=:email AND `password`=:password";
    $pdoResult=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $pdoExec=$pdoResult->execute(array(":email"=>$email,":password"=>$password));
    $pdoResult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count=0;
    $uid='';
    while ($r=$pdoResult->fetch()) {
      # code...
    $count+=1;
    $uid=$r['email'];
    }

    if ($count==1) {
      # code...
      $_SESSION['can-id']=$uid;
      header('location: ../home/profile.php');

    }
    else
    {
      $_SESSION['error']="login failed";
    }
    }
    ?>

<html>
....
</html>
```

profile.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    if (!(isset($_SESSION['can-id']))) {
        # code...
        header('location: ../login/');

    }
    else
    {
        $cid=$_SESSION['can-id'];
    }
?>
<h1 ><?php echo $cid;?></h1>
```

This is my code after log in the page was redirected to profile.php page but in profile page session variable doesn't printed I don't know why but this problem was not occuring every time I log in It occurs sometimes so I can't find what is the problem. Anyone knows  please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Check this is the very top of the profile.php, any output prior to this script will render the `header` ineffective. Should maybe `exit` after `header`? Also use [password_hash](https://code-boxx.com/password-encrypt-decrypt-php/) for passwords rather than plain text storage.

Comment: According to your script, your profile page should redirect to the login page if the session variable is not there.  Is it redirecting?

Comment: Yeah! It's redirecting if session not set

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  ob_start() from your login.php
Don't put session_start() in all of your file

```
 e.g login.php, profile.php, etc
```

but instead, add this to your config.php for example:

```
<?php 
 session_start(); 
 //.. config variables here
```

Then, include config.php also in your profile.php.

Comment: Yeah it works fine after removing ob_start(). But why ob_start causes such a problem.

Comment: it doesn't work because you need to use ‎Ob_get_contents, Ob_end_flush.  In your example, Output buffer is not needed. However, you can read more about it here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#93633